# Почему не нравится компилятору?

Tags: typescript

```
function overlord(x: string): void
function overlord(x: number): void
function overlord(x: any): void {

}

function test(x: string | number): void {
    overlord(x)
}
```

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Typescript 3.0 [Ссылка на демо](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20overlord(x%3A%20string)%3A%20void%0D%0Afunction%20overlord(x%3A%20number)%3A%20void%0D%0Afunction%20overlord(x%3A%20any)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(x%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20overlord(x)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Разве то, что я написал выше, не является "явным описанием проблемы"?

Comment: Нет, не являлось. Хорошо хоть Qwertiy добавил текст сообщения об ошибке ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что тайпскрипт не умет так объединять различные типы. Рекомендуется всегда объявлять как можно меньше перегрузок с указанием ветвления типов внутри, если это возможно. Если же по некоторой причине требуется выполнить именно такой вызов, то стоит добавить `as any`:

```
overlord(x as any)
```